# VIEW cascade on insert then dump to table / VIEW instead of trigger then dump to table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, triggers

I want to dump view data to a table.I have a VIEW that does a lot of case/algorithms/ like this: (dont concern yourself with this code just yet...)

```
    select  c1.a as car, c1.b as boat, c1.c as tree    convert(char(1),
 dbo.aa(l1+l12+l314)) as something1,    convert(varchar(9), dbo.bb(l1+l1+l13+l14, 2)) 
as something2,   bo.bb(l1+l12+l13+l14, 3) as something3,    convert(char(1),
 dbo.aa(l1+l1+l1+l14)) as something4, case when dbo.aa(l1+l12+l13+l14, 2) like 
'ttt'  then convert(varchar(20), bb(l1+l12+l13+l14, 5))     
 else null ............... etc..
```

On insert I want this VIEW's data to be dumped into a table.

DO I hard code a cascade on insert when I create this view? **OR**

DO I create a instead of trigger on insert to dump to table?

Either way, how would I code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't insert via the view. If the view has complex logic in it, it may be *impossible* to map back to the underlying table/s and an insert might not be possible.

For example, using your sample: if the view is updated to have a different value for the `something1` field, how is this value to be de-constructed to the correct underlying values for `l1`, `l12` and `l314`?

Use a stored procedure instead and ensure that the application uses that and does not attempt to update the view.

You can create triggers on all the underlying tables that will query the view and update the data in the extra table you want, though this seems to defeat the point of the view.

Comment: @user719825 - It won't. You need to structure you application to use the SP for inserts instead of the view.

Comment: To structure you mean a job? or make the Sp run via trigger?

Comment: @user719825 - I mean in application code, in your data access. You can't update this complex view and expect correct results in the underlying tables.

Comment: I understand what you mean,  but my only concern is when would the SP be executed? the VIEW updates by itself. THE SP would have to be executed everytime a record is created in one of the underlining tables (the tables that create the view.)

Comment: How can the view update by itself??? Something must update the underlying tables.

Comment: What I mean is the view is based on tables. When a record is entered into tables A B C, the view obtains those records. How would the SP do this, without being executed by a trigger or job?

Comment: You can create triggers on all the underlying tables that will query the view and update the data in the table you need.

Comment: Ok that is possible,but then I wouldnt need an SP?